# how to avoid repeated counts in counting repeated numbers if the number appeared three times?

Tags: java

```
public static int countRepeats(int[] items) {
    int l=items.length;
    int num=0;
    int[] count=new int[l];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<l;j++){
            if(items[i]==items[j]){
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(count[i]>0){
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

//{1,2,1,3,4,5,5}should give 2;2numbers repeated
//{0,0,0} but my code give 2 for this one..

Comment: can i use while loops??

Answer (score 1):

From your code, array `{0, 0, 0}`, the first element will be counted as 2, the second element will be counted as 1, then the last one will be counted as 0, of course, it gives you 2. Try this:

```
public static int countRepeats(int[] items) {
    int num = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Integer i : items) {
        if (countMap.containsKey(i)) { // check if map does contain the key or not, if does, make this key'value +1;
            countMap.put(i, countMap.get(i) + 1);
        } else { // if not contain the key, just put it as a new key and the value is 1.
            countMap.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    for (Integer item : countMap.values()) {
        if (item > 1) {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Use a `Map` to store the number's appear times, then get all the values in this map, count the value which is over 1 then you can get what you want.

Comment: In Java 8 you can do `for (int i : items) countMap.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not correct. Not sure about your input, but if all numbers are positive and not very big (not big enough to worry about memory), you may try this. It can handle any number of repeats.

```
public static int countRepeats(int[] items) {
    int l=items.length;
    int num=0;
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(items[i] > max) max = items[i];  // get the largest number
    }
    int[] count=new int[max + 1];  // assume count elements are initiated with 0
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
       count[items[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=max;i++){
        if(count[i]>1){
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets only store distinct items. You can use one set to find duplicates and another to store them distinctly, then return the size of the latter set:

```
public static int countRepeats(int[] items) {
    Set<Integer> distinct = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> duplicate = new HashSet<>();
    for (int item : items) {
        if (!distinct.add(item)) {
            // item was already contained in set
            duplicate.add(item);
        }
    }
    return duplicate.size();
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

The Map maybe helpful,just like:

```
   public static int countRepeats(int[] items) {
        int res = 0;
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i:items){
            map.put(i, map.get(i)==null?0:map.get(i)+1);
        }

        for(Integer key:map.keySet()){
            if(map.get(key)>0){
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Is this in any way different from Forward's answer?

Comment: I just didn't see his answer :-D

Comment: I think Forward's answer reads better even though they do exactly the same thing overall. The `?` operation is what I find a little trickier to read. But my some what limited knowledge on the `HashMap` says that this maybe faster for larger sets of data due to absents of calling `containsKey()`. (Anyone who knows better is welcome to correct me).

Comment: It effectively replaces `containsKey(i)` with `get(i) == null` so I doubt whether it's faster.  I apologise for my earlier remark though - it's clearly a _little bit_ different, though not particularly much.

Comment: I think they have the same effciency . The `containsKey(i)` code is `return getEntry(key) != null;`,and method `get(Object key)` is `Entry<K,V> entry = getEntry(key); return null == entry ? null : entry.getValue();`.They all use `getEntry(key)`.